# Saving receipts for money withdrawn from 529 plan

Tags: united-states, withdrawal, 529-plan

I am planning to withdraw the full amount of ‘Cost of attendance’ given by school for a semester from 529 plan.

1. Can I withdraw money for expenses towards off-campus room and board for a full semester (4 months)?
2. Do I have to save receipts even if I withdraw amount equal to COA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am planning to withdraw the full amount of ‘Cost of attendance’
> given by school for a semester from 529 plan.

If you are also wanting to clam the American opportunity Credit which is also in [pub 970](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p970#en_US_2021_publink100077339):

> Figuring the Credit
>
> The amount of the American opportunity credit (per eligible student)
> is the sum of:
>
> 1. 100% of the first $2,000 of qualified education expenses you paid for the eligible student, and
> 2. 25% of the next $2,000 of qualified education expenses you paid for that student.

Then the $2,000 or $4,000 must come from non-529 funds. I am assuming there were no scholarships involved.

This credit means that $2,000 that would have gone to the IRS will instead help pay for college. That was something I wasn't aware of until another parent told me about it.

Note there is also a MAGI limit:

> Effect of the Amount of Your Income on the Amount of Your Credit
>
> The amount of your American opportunity credit is phased out
> (gradually reduced) if your MAGI is between $80,000 and $90,000
> ($160,000 and $180,000 if you file a joint return). You can't claim an
> American opportunity credit if your MAGI is $90,000 or more ($180,000
> or more if you file a joint return).

Yes keep all receipts. This is always good advice regarding taxes. Also keeping those receipts can be a big help when double checking the 1098-T and 1099-Q.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I withdraw money for expenses towards off-campus room and board for a full semester (4 months)?

Yes, if you are enrolled as at least half-time student for the course of study you're pursuing (see the [IRS Pub. 970](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p970#en_US_2021_publink100077339)).

> Do I have to save receipts even if I withdraw amount equal to COA?

You should *always* save receipts and document everything you're reporting the the IRS. Pub. 970 (see link above) says that *...the expense must be incurred...*, i.e.: if audited you might be required to prove that you actually paid for room and board.